# generating a binary buffer with python to be read in C as a struct

Tags: python, c

I have the following struct in my C program:

```
typedef struct
{
 void* str;
 DWORD str_length;
 DWORD count;

} mystruct;
```

I would like to create a buffer in Python, write it to a file, and then read it from my C program, and reference this buffer as a "mystruct".

what I tried in python was:

```
from struct import *

str = raw_input("str: ")
count = raw_input("count: ")

s = Struct ( str(len(str)) + 'sLL' )
s.pack( str , len(str) , int(count))
```

it returns a binary buffer , but not with my data.

where have I got it wrong? is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The struct does not comtain space for the string! So I suggest to declare as `struct { char str[120]; DWORD str_length, count; }`. The length of the string should be tailored to your needs.

Comment: TrueY is right. Read the documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). To pack a "void *" you should use 'P', instead of 's'. But, since you want a string, you should change the C struct, as he told you.

Comment: you're right ofcourse , but my problem is before I even try reading it in C. it's the output of pack() in python that doesn't seems to reflect my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm preferring using ctypes for this kind of job. It gives more options in handling pointers. Here is an example how your issue could be resolved using ctypes (in Python 3.x but you can easily convert it to Python 2.x).
Your structure still doesn't contains data. Only pointer to buffer that is accessible from C code. This buffer is created using create_string_buffer that convert python string to C null terminated one.

```
from ctypes import *

class mystruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("str", c_char_p),
                ("str_length", c_long),
                ("count", c_long)]

s = b"ABC" * 10
c = 44

#convert python string to null terminated c char array
c_str = create_string_buffer(s)
#cast char array to char*
c_str_pointer = cast(c_str, c_char_p)
#create structure
a = mystruct(c_str_pointer, len(s), c)

# print byte representation of structure
print(bytes(a))

print(a.str)
print(a.str_length)
print(a.count)
```

If you don't need pointers and constant buffer is enough you can also do this using ctypes

```
from ctypes import *

class mystruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("str", c_char*100),
                ("str_length", c_long),
                ("count", c_long)]

s = b"ABC" * 10
c = 44

a = mystruct(s, len(s), c)

# print byte representation of structure
print(bytes(a))

print(a.str)
print(a.str_length)
print(a.count)
```